# django for loop random order determine

Tags: python, django, for-loop, random

I want to have a tag list of 10 main tags but displayed in random order because the font weight will determine their weight.

first i order objects and get 10 tags, than I use shuffle to randomise the order. So far it works. My issue now is to use {{forloop.counter0}} in template which outputs below code in random order:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="tag-0">Tag3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tag-1">Tag1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tag-2">Tag2</td>
    </tr>
```

Instead I want it to be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tag-2">Tag3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tag-0">Tag1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tag-1">Tag2</td>
</tr>
```

template:

```
{% for t in tags %}
    <tr>
        <td class="tag-{{forloop.counter0}}">{{t.title}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

in views:

```
tags = list(Model.objects.order_by('title')[:10])
random.shuffle(tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a model manager to do your initial filtering, and then randomize the order of the objects in your view. You want to try to take a "fat" model, "thin" view approach. The more you can do in your model, the easier changes will be down the road. For example,

***models.py:***

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_titles(self):
        return super(FooManager, self).get_queryset.order_by('title')

class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    objects = FooManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

***views.py:***

```
def view(request):
    get_titles = Foo.objects.get_titles()[:10]
    titles = list(get_titles)
    random.shuffle(titles)

    context = {
        'titles': titles
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Your templates become a lot easier, too.

***html:***

```
{% for t in titles %}
    {{ t.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope that helps! Good luck!